# Getting data to callback method

Tags: java, callback, code-reuse

I have the following code and architecture (in fact this is a very simplified version) consting of a abstract and a concrete class.

```
public abstract class AbstractProcessor {
    public void updateDataFromUrl(String url) {
        //Download url
        //Decrypt, and do a lot of stuff, 
        String data = "abc"; //Result from downloading

        String processed = processData(data);

        //Do a lot of other things with the transformed data
    }

    public abstract String processData(String data);
}


final class ConcreteProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    public void updateData(int year, int month, int day) {
        String url = String.format("http://%d.%d.%d", year, month, day);
        updateDataFromUrl(url);
    }

    @Override
    public String processData(String data) {
        //Process the data

        //---------------
        //PROBLEM:
        //----------------
        //Need access to year, month, day ....

        return null;
    }
}
```

The `updateDataFromUrl` method contains a lot of code (booth, before and after the `processData` call) which I want to reuse in several Processors, for this reason I put the code into a abstract class.

The problem is: **I want to access the data which was provided to the newly added `updateData` method (here `year`, `month`, `day`). As the call flows through the abstract class which does not know of these parameters, this information gets lost. How can I modify this architecture to keep this information?**

The following solutions came to my mind, all with obvious drawbacks:

1. Provide the abstract method with the url and extract the parameters from there again. (Problem: What is there are parameters which I only need in the `procecssData` method and never in the url?)
2. Split the `updateDataFromUrl` method into two two methods (the part before the `processData` call and the part afterwards). Now use these methods directly in the ConcreteProcessor. (Problem: The `updateDataFromUrl` method has a lot of context which I need both, before and after the `processData` call. How can I get this data transfered between the newly created methods?)

Comment: How about a "state" Object. `public abstract String processData(String data, Object state);` You can make state anything and your abstract class just forward it, and your concrete implementation will know what it is ...

Comment: @Fildor I thought about the same, but isn't this approach a little hacky? I'm not sure about this....

Comment: Well, at least it would be the least change to the code as it is right now. Though it _is_ hacky compared to ewernli's 2nd approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only minor modifications lead to this solution (if I didn't miss some point (untested)).

You get the following benefits:

- information passing is very straightforward (using instance variables)
- you retain thread-safety
- from an external (public) view, `ConcreteProcessor` can remain immutable

It would probably be best not to return a `ConcreteProcessor` from `updateData` but some immutable type that represents the transformed data.

```
public abstract class AbstractProcessor {
    public void updateDataFromUrl(String url) {
        //Download url
        //Decrypt, and do a lot of stuff, 
        String data = "abc"; //Result from downloading

        String processed = processData(data);

        //Do a lot of other things with the transformed data
    }

    public abstract String processData(String data);
}


final class ConcreteProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    public static ConcreteProcessor updateData(int year, int month, int day) {
            ConcreteProcessor p = new ConcreteProcessor(year, month, day);
            p.updateDataFromUrl(url);
            return p;
    }

    private /* instance vars for year, month, day, url, ... */

    private ConcreteProcessor(int year, int month, int day) {
            this.year = year;
            this.month = month;
            this.day = day;
            this.url = String.format("http://%d.%d.%d", year, month, day);
    }


    @Override
    public String processData(String data) {
        //Process the data

        //---------------
        // NO PROBLEM:
        //----------------
        //Easy to access to year, month, day using the instance vars

        return null;
    }
}
```

But the overall concept looks like a linear pipeline and therefore it would probably be best to make the pipeline more explicit. You will need some kind of state carrying but that shouldn't be a big problem using generics I think.

Answer (score 2):

Two ideas:

1. Use instance variables in `ConcreteProcessor` to store year, month, day. Both methods can access the instance variable of the object. They are not accessible to the abstract class, though. Beware: the object is not thread-safe any longer. You must have multiple independent processors to process data concurrently.
2. Reverse the dependency and use composition. A generic class `Processor` contains the common logic. When you invoke `updateDataFromUrl` you also pass an instance of a `ProcessingStrategy` that implements `processData` (indeed a kind of callback).

There are probably several variations of the ideas that are possible.

Comment: I would advise similarly, but with one clarification: redesign to use a per-request instance of `Processor`, or use `Processor` as a factory of such per-request objects. Follow the example of Java `Pattern` and `Matcher`.

Comment: Well I actually came up with the first idea, but I do not want to destroy the thread safety. Could you go into more detail with the second answer? I do not fully understand this. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @theomega If you design along the lines of my comment, this avoids any multithreading issues.